# Do orcas react differently to swimmers in orca-like dresses?

Tags: behaviour

Question on animal behaviour. [This video](https://youtu.be/52o5yV6G7tY) shows the trainers of the orcas in swimming pool with them. Why do they use orca-like dresses? Is it just for the show, or do orcas then treat them more peacefully? :)

[image]

Comment: there is an "ethology" tag already :)

Comment: To close-voter(s): this question can definitely be answered without the use of opinion, so I disagree regarding the VTCs. I vote to keep open.

Comment: This is hard to answer and doesn't seem to have been directly studied anywhere. However, my guess is that it's just for the show. Orcas readily eat penguins and Commerson's dolphins, which are both at least as 'dressed like' them as the humans are in this picture.